# Output random string from Array C# Console

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

```
string[] aNames = new string[10] { "Ronaldo", "Messi", "Aguero", "Dembele", "Reus", "Mbappe", "Sane", "Sterling", "Ibrahimovic", "Alaba" };
```

This is my array. I need to output a random string from this array into the console, and then once the name has been outputted the user must input the first name of the to win, if they get it wrong they lose, any help on doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```C#
using System;

public class Program
{
    private static string[] aNames = new string[10] { "Ronaldo", "Messi", "Aguero", "Dembele", "Reus", "Mbappe", "Sane", "Sterling", "Ibrahimovic", "Alaba" };
    private static string[] FirstNames = new string[10] {"Cristiano", "Lionel", "Sergio", "Ousmane", "Marco", "Kylian", "Leroy", "Raheem", "Zlatan", "David" };
    private static int randomIndex = -1;
    private static String UserInput = "";

    public static void Main()
    {
        ShowQuestion();
    }


    private static void ShowQuestion()
    {
        Random rd = new Random();
        randomIndex = rd.Next(0, aNames.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the First Name of "+aNames[randomIndex]);
        GetUserInput();
    }
    private static void GetUserInput()
    {
        UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("You Entered : "+UserInput);
        CheckTheAnswer();       
    }

    private static void CheckTheAnswer()
    {
        if (string.Equals(UserInput, FirstNames[randomIndex], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You Win");
                RePlay();

            }else{
                Console.WriteLine("You Lose");
                RePlay();
            }
    }

    private static void RePlay()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("To reply enter Y else N");
        UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
        switch(UserInput)
        {
            case "Y":
            case "y":
                ShowQuestion();
            break;
            default:
              System.Environment.Exit(1);
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

Try this, more info at [Random.Next Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx)